# How to fix "The maximum permissible key length is 900 bytes."

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Formats]
    (
        [caption_id] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL,
        Formats_exist BIT NOT NULL
    )
Result-: 1 row created

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Formats] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [pk__formats] 
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([caption_id] ASC);

Result-: 1 row created 


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Signature]
    (
        [caption_id] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL,
        [signature_id] [int] NOT NULL
    )

Result-: 1 row created


    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Signature] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [pk__signatures] 
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([caption_id] ASC,[signature_id] ASC);
```

Result-:

```
Msg 1944, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Index 'pk__signatures' was not created. This index has a key length of at least 1028 bytes. The maximum permissible key length is 900 bytes.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

why i am getting the error for above primary key while am not getting error for the first one though it was `nvarchar(512)` and it is more than 900 bytes.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I also get the error on both statements.

An NVARCHAR takes 2 bytes of storage.

512 x 2 = 1024 bytes.

Do you need 512 chars ?